# Remote image embedders fail with "no internet connection"

Tags: orange

I'm following the [Orange "Getting Started" YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu8g2Twjn9U&t=192s) and noticed that the Inception v3 image embedder (and any of the other remote services for that matter) all fail with the message:

```
"No internet connection: switched to local embedder."
```

[image]

My computer has an internet connection (obviously I am posting here...). Has anyone else encountered this? Is there some API key or other authentication necessary to use these remote embedder services?  It reverted to using SqueezeNet on my local machine which still works, but I was hoping to experiment with the different services to see how it affects the image classification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this out. It appears to have been a transient issue at the server level that is now resolved both for myself and someone else experiencing the same problem. [image]